# there is a loading cursor in visual studio build program, will not stop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I made a small program ( in visual studio 2013) that simply displays a label in Form1 and a message when closing it. However, when I open it, it has the loading cursor that never stops. Can anyone help me please?

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim response As MsgBoxResult
    response = MsgBox("Skype must be restarted.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Confirm")
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        Me.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: The Visual **Studio** loading cursor never changes or your program never changes?

Comment: There is no need to call `Dispose` inside of the `FormClosing` event handler. The form is going to close anyway. If you want to *prevent* it from being closed, then you need to set `e.Cancel` to true.

Answer (score 0):

### Cause of Error?

Look, I can't clearly say what the error is, but I find, the two main things because of which you are getting the error are:

- There is a background task in your computer who is generating this, or, your `Visual Studio`'s Environment is taking too long to load it's features.
- The second error may be that, **your cursor is set to loading**.

### Steps to Overcome

You need to go to your `form`'s properties and set the cursor property to `default` or whatever you want. This can do your work, if you are having the second problem. 
You can set different `cursor` property for different controls.

I hope this helps!